# Jira plugin is not working properly on VS Code

Tags: jira, vscode-extensions

I use to work with VS Code and the Atlassian plugin for Jira. It have been working quite well since few months on.

Right now I'm not able to create a new issue, neither open an existing (assignated) issue, and create a branch from there.

did you experienced similar issue? how can I solve.

i've been searching everywhere but nothing cames out.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: Same, I am able to view the issue but while creating I get empty tab :(